# Configure fixed listening port on RDP api

Tags: c#, rdp, wds

I wrote a windows desktop sharing app using Microsoft RDP COM API.

```
activeSession = new RDPSession();

/* I can only have 1 attendee per-session */
activeSession.Invitations.CreateInvitation(authstr, groupname, password, 1);
```

but I need to start an RDP session at a given port (due to firewall policies) every time I generate an invitation to a session, instead of a random one.

Does anyone know a way to do that with that API? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way digging up a little bit [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/rdpencomapi/nf-rdpencomapi-irdpsrapisessionproperties-put_property).

```
activeSession.Properties["PortId"] = listeningPort;
activeSession.Open();
```